# SSRS - Auto Refresh of the Data Set Fields

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

We have about 90 Report Builder Reports built by power users. These reports are built off the 20 odd Base reporting tables.

Once in a while we add new fields to these reporting tables.

The challenge here is to automatically refresh the Datasets in Report Builder (SSRS) without having to go through each report to manually refresh data on the data set. Since SSRS processes these reports with FMTONLY ON is there a way to automate this process dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: No these are views of selections from relational tables

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you should use [report models](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678411.aspx)
A report model is made from a datasource view and once the DSV is updated, it reflects on the report model and consequently on all reports.

I dont think there is a way of doing it when the reports automatically connect to the DB

Comment: Is there a possibility to execute the query/stored procedure without having to refresh the dataset.