# How to refresh dataset dynamically in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, dataset, ssrs-2012

I have a dataset which gets its value from a shared data source. The Shared Data source gets it's value by querying a sql table in which new columns are added everyday.

I need to display the table with these new columns in a matrix in ssrs report.

How can I refresh the dataset fields automatically so that I need not go and manually refresh its fields everytime a new column is added in the table?

My question is same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385552/ssrs-auto-refresh-of-the-data-set-fields) one where [Report Models](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678411.aspx) is suggested. Is there any other possibility?

[As I am not allowed to post a comment there (being new to the site), I am posing this as a separate question.]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Right now this appears to be a duplicate of the question you have referenced and it's also very broad, if that solution does not work then explain why it doesn't.  Have you tried any other solutions?  Including code, etc that you also tried would be very helpful.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks much for responding. Sorry to have not mentioned that the version of my SQL server is 2012 in which Report models are not supported. (here's the reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778040/ssrs-2012-report-models)
You can very well answer in the original question.  Would be nice if someone answers somewhere.. Thanks :)